# SQL Rows to column but NOT transpose

Tags: sql, hive

We have a table regarding identification where data is as such:

| Customer Number | Identification |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | passport-us |
| 101 | Licence |
| 102 | passport-uk |
| 102 | Licence |
| 102 | birth-cert |
| 103 | Licence-learner |

Thus one customer may have submitted multiple identification others in varying number/combination.

Result we are after is :

| Customer Number | Passport | Licence | Birth Certificate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | passport-us | licence |  |
| 102 | passport-uk | licence | birth-cert |
| 103 |  | licence-learner |  |

So basically taking the exact text and placing in the subsequent column.

What we know is:

- there are only three identification type we are interested in (if there are others we dont catch)
- they will contain within it the keyword (passport,birth, etc)
- there is no given order to how customer number is coming in the table, there is a separate primary key else where in the bigger table.
- we are aiming the query to run in hive

I was thinking along the lines of self join three times with REGEXP_EXTRACT perhaps.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using pure sql like this:

```
select
  CustomerNumber,
  max(case when Identification like 'passport%' then Identification else null end) as Passport,
  max(case when Identification like 'Licence%' then Identification else null end) as Licence,
  max(case when Identification ='birth-cert' then Identification else null end) as BirthCertificate
from identification
group by CustomerNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to transpose when you have a limited number of known values to transpose is to do a groupby.

If you are sure that there is a maximum of 1 of each type for each user, you can use something like the below:

```
select
    customer_number
    , arbitrary(case when regexp_like(identification, 'passport-') then identification end ) as passport
    , arbitrary(case when regexp_like(identification, 'license-') then identification end ) as passport
    , arbitrary(case when regexp_like(identification, 'birth-cert') then identification end ) as passport
from table
group by customer_number
```

If your sql dialect do not have `arbitrary` you can try using `coalesce`. Either will return the first non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a subquery to help construct this by selecting the passport, licence, and birth certificates into their own columns.

Something like this:

```
SELECT  CustomerNumber,
        MAX(Passport) AS Passport,
        MAX(Licence) AS Licence,
        MAX(BirthCertificate) AS BirthCertificate
  FROM  (
        SELECT  CustomerNumber,
                CASE
                  WHEN LENGTH(Identification) >= 8 AND LEFT(Identification, 8) = 'passport' THEN Identification
                  ELSE NULL
                END AS Passport,
                CASE
                  WHEN LENGTH(Identification) >= 7 AND LEFT(Identification, 7) = 'licence' THEN Identification
                  ELSE NULL
                END AS Licence,
                CASE
                  WHEN LENGTH(Identification) >= 5 AND LEFT(Identification, 5) = 'birth' THEN Identification
                  ELSE NULL
                END AS BirthCertificate
          FROM  Customer
        ) a
  GROUP BY CustomerNumber
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5eA99XJrbbL3kr4eSVt1ot/0).

Output:

| CustomerNumber | Passport | Licence | BirthCertificate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | passport-us | Licence |  |
| 102 | passport-uk | Licence | birth-cert |
| 103 |  | Licence-learner |  |